# Remove TabGroup tab title and show only icon on Appcelerator app for iOS

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

How can I hide the "title" text in the tabs in a TabGroup in an Appcelerator app for iOS?

By default, if I just leave the title attribute blank, it leaves extra space where the title would usually appear.

How it appears with "title" text:

[image]

How it appears without "title" text:

[image]

How I want it to appear:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fix works, though it is a little hackish:

1. Go to `/Users/[yourname]/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.1.0.GA/iphone/Classes/`
2. Open the file "TiUITabProxy.m" in Appcelerator Studio and make the following updates.
3. In TiUITabProxy.m search for "(void)updateTabBarItem" and insert this line:

   `[ourItem setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0)];`

   right before the following line at the very end of the function:

   `[rootController setTabBarItem:ourItem];`
4. Clean your project and rebuild.

There is an opened JIRA ticket for this to add this to Titanium proper: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-18515

*The solution was originally provided in the Appcelerator Community forums at https://community.appcelerator.com/topic/2878/remove-tabgroup-tab-title-and-show-only-icon-on-ios/7*